# Delete with WHERE - date, time and string comparison - very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a slow performing query and was hoping someone with a bit more knowledge in sql might be able to help me improve the performance:

I have 2 tables a Source and a Common, I load in some data which contains a Date, a Time and String (whch is a server name), plus some..

The Source table can contain 40k+ rows (it has 30 odd columns, a mix of ints, dates, times and some varchars (255)/(Max)

I use the below query to remove any data from Common that is in source:

`'Delete from Common where convert(varchar(max),Date,102)+convert(varchar(max),Time,108)+[ServerName] in 
(Select convert(varchar(max),[date],102)+convert(varchar(max),time,108)+ServerName from Source where sc_status < 300)'`

**The Source Fields are in this format:**

- ServerName varchar(255) ***I.E*** SN1234
- Date varchar(255) ***I.E*** 2012-05-22
- Time varchar(255) ***I.E*** 08:12:21

**The Common Fields are in this format:**

- ServerName varchar(255) ***I.E*** SN1234
- Date date ***I.E*** 2011-08-10
- Time time(7) ***I.E*** 14:25:34.0000000

Thanks

Comment: Which table is which? Both labels say `Source`... and why does one table store the date/time data as massive strings? What is their exact format? We can't guess at these things. Please show us some sample data...

Comment: Why are you using varchar(255) for Date and Time fields?

Comment: The Source table stores these as varchars because of logparser and the way we have used it. I updated the post for the Common Table formats.

ALso added an example next to each. Hope this Helps

Comment: Why are concatenating them into one string? I highly recomend further Sql training, do something like this in an interview test, and you are toast.

Comment: The Data is IIS Logs and some entries from the logs can be duplicates... So I was just doing it from ServerName, Date and Time. So I could load in a log several times a day.

I completely agree, I do need more training and I am activly reading and trying. 

I had tomake it as quick as possible and My SQL is poor. I apologise.

Comment: Can you describe how the IIS Log data gets into the `Source` table? I know you are using logparser but can you be more specific about the actual insert into `Source`? Is it using `BULK INSERT`, `SqlBulkCopy`, something else?

Comment: @TomEaton. Apology unnecesssary, just wanted to make sure you knew there was some learning to do. It's the people who don't think they do, that need to aplogise profusely and often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting both sides to strings, then concatenating them into one big string, then comparing those results is not very efficient. Only do conversions where you have to. Try this example and see how it compares:

```
DELETE c
  FROM dbo.Common AS c
  INNER JOIN dbo.Source AS s
  ON s.ServerName = c.ServerName
  AND CONVERT(DATE, s.[Date]) = c.[Date]
  AND CONVERT(TIME(7), s.[Time]) = c.[Time]
  WHERE s.sc_status < 300;
```

Comment: This solution looks pretty good.  The main thing is to avoid converts and string concats. I wonder if it is necessary to convert the s.Date and s.Time columns.

Comment: @bjorsig If you don't explicitly do it, it's going to do it anyway as an implicit conversion.

Comment: I liked explicit myself, also imagine if the date coming from the log parser was a different locale to the one in the database, at least you can slot the expected format straight in and get a decent error message.

Answer (score 0):

All those conversions to `VARCHAR(MAX)` are unnecessary and probably slowing you down. I would start with something like this instead:

```
DELETE c
from [Common] c
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Source
    WHERE CAST([Date] AS DATE)=c.[Date]
    AND CAST([Time] AS TIME(7))=c.[Time]
    AND [ServerName]=c.[ServerName]
    AND sc_status < 300
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Delete from Common inner join Source 
On Common.ServerName = Source.ServerName 
and Common.Date = Convert(Date,Source.Date)
and Common.Time = Convert(Time, Source.Time)
And Source.sc_Status < 300
```

If it's too slow after that, then you need some indexes, possible on both tables.

Comment: Index on `Source.Date` and `Source.Time` won't really help since the conversions will still have to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the unecessary conversions will help a lot as detailed in Aaron's answer. You might also consider creating an indexed view over the top of the log table, since you probably dont have much flexibility in that schema or insert DML from the log parser.

Simple example:

```
create table dbo.[Source] (LogId int primary key, servername varchar(255), 
   [date] varchar(255), [time] varchar(255));
insert into dbo.[Source]
    values  (1, 'SN1234', '2012-05-22', '08:12:21'),
            (2, 'SN5678', '2012-05-23', '09:12:21')
go

create view dbo.vSource with schemabinding
as
    select  [LogId],
            [servername], 
            [date], 
            [time], 
            [actualDateTime] = convert(datetime, [date]+' '+[time], 120)
    from    dbo.[Source];
go

create unique clustered index UX_Source on vSource(LogId);
create nonclustered index IX_Source on vSource(actualDateTime);
```

This will give you an indexed datetime column on which to seek and vastly improve your execution plans at the cost of some insert performance.

Comment: You probably meant to have `convert(datetime, [date] + ' ' + [time], 120)` in the view definition. However this is going to be a very expensive view to maintain for the bulk loading process. I'd almost rather add a computed column to that table instead of this entire materialized view, if the bulk load process can deal with columns it can't touch.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! A computed column would definitely be ideal if the OP can alter the schema without breaking his log parser.  Good point Aaron.